# Use of prototype constructor in JS

Tags: javascript, oop

Can someone explain to me use of `Me.prototype.constructor = Me;` and why is needed, when this code is working and without it?

In code prototype object is created on Me object and it is instantiated and replaced old prototype object. Why do I need to point to Me constructor in a given up code?

```
function Me(){
    this.name = 'Dejan';

}

function You(){
    this.name = 'Ivan';
}

Me.prototype = new You();

somebody = new Me();

Me.prototype.constructor = Me; // Why?

Me.prototype.foo = function(){
    alert('Proto Me!'); // It always fire up this alert, ether constructor is pointing to Me or not... !
}

You.prototype.foo = function(){
    alert('Proto You!');
}

somebody.foo();
alert(somebody.name); // Alert 'Dejan'
```

Comment: I believe legacy browsers check `.constructor` property for `instanceof` keyword.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not needed, and it's not even needed for `instanceof` contrary to popular belief (instanceof internally checks the prototype chain and does not need a constructor property). Normally, `constructor` is inherently a non-enumerable property on a constructor's `prototype`. Thus giving any objects instantiated by that constructor, a non-enumerable `constructor` property, pointing to that constructor.

It's good to put it there if you need to, ideally non-enumerable. Some code will assume the existence of `.constructor` on objects.

In the code you posted, yes, when doing inheritance that way, it's necessary to reset constructor (if you want it there), because the object you instantiated to act as the child prototype has a constructor property pointing to the wrong constructor (its constructor).

In ES5, you would do:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
  constructor: { value: Child, enumerable: false }
});
```

edit: Also, might be worth mentioning, when doing inheritance using the non-standard `__proto__`, it's not necessary to reset constructor because `__proto__` merely specifies and object's prototype, which it to say, the object on which lookups will be performed when an own property doesn't exist. A new `prototype` will always have a property called `constructor`.

So in doing:

```
var child = function() {};
child.prototype.__proto__ = parent.prototype;
```

You do not have to set constructor because child.prototype's base constructor property is still there. If accessed, no prototype chain lookups need to be performed.

Comment: Are you sure IE6 doesn't check `constructor` property? And `Object.create` sets the `constructor` property for you. You dont have to do it manually

Comment: Raynos, No I'm not sure about IE6, given that I don't really care about IE6. Also, Object.create does not set constructor for you, it has no concept of a constructor, in fact, that's the point of Object.create. You would only get a constructor property equal to the parent constructor, which would be wrong for inheritance. So you need to change it.

Comment: your right my bad about the `constructor`. Object.create has no concept of constructor

Answer (score 5):

If you replace the line

```
Me.prototype.constructor = Me; // Why?
```

with

```
console.log(Me.prototype.constructor);
Me.prototype.constructor = Me; // Why?
```

you will find that before setting it, `Me.prototype.constructor` is `You`, since `Me.prototype` is an instance of `You` due to the line

```
Me.prototype = new You();
```

So, the line with the `// Why?` comment is necessary to "fix" this mistaken impression that you've given JavaScript by doing inheritance this way.

---

Essentially the problem comes about because you are trying to use prototypal inheritance to implement classical inheritance. Prototypal inheritance works on object instances, and has no concept of "classes" or even, really, "types," but JavaScript makes things extra confusing with the whole `new`, `.constructor`, and `instanceof` business.

A more prototypal way of doing this kind of thing is to eschew constructors in favor of power constructors, i.e. functions that return an object with the form you desire:

```
function begetPart(partNumber,  description) {
    return Object.create({}, {
        number: { value: partNumber },
        description: { value: description },
        describe: {
            value: function () {
                alert(this.description);
            }
        }
    });
}

function begetTire(partNumber, speed) {
    return Object.create(
        begetPart(partNumber, "A tire"),
        {
            speed: { value: speed },
            describe: {
                value: function () {
                    alert(this.description + "; speed = " + this.speed);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}

var genericPart = begetPart(1234, "A widget");
genericPart.describe(); // alerts "A widget"

var tire = begetTire(4567, "fast");
tire.describe(); // alerts "A tire; speed = fast"
```

Here we use `Object.create` to say "create an object instance based on this other object instance". The other instance is a new, empty object for `begetPart` and a new "part instance" with some properties pre-filled for `begetTire`.

This better reflects how JavaScript and prototypal inheritance actually works, since in prototypal inheritance object instances inherit from other object instances, without this whole "types" or "classes" idea getting in the way.